# angular2: loop a json list, NaN

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Probably sthg stupid but when I loop a json list and increment a value inside this list then I always get NaN (despite the types are *number*).

**Here is what I tried :**

```
export class PaymentPage   {

    total_amount:number;

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
          public products: ProductsService) {

               var MyProducts=[
               {
                 "amount": 999,
                 ...
                 },
                 {
                 "amount": 4900,
                  ...
                  }
                ];

              var amount:number;
              for (var product in MyProducts) {
                amount += (MyProducts[product]['amount'])*MyProducts[product]['quantity'];
              }
              this.total_amount=amount/100
```

Any idea?

Comment: is it at all possible that quantity in your `MyProducts` array is a string?

Comment: You have to initialize `amount` like `var amount = 0;`. Note that by initializing it the type gets inferred and doesn't have to be stated explicitly.

Comment: Parse your value befor multiply

Comment: You have amount, but no quantity. Please share the array with quantity.

Comment: @Tao thank you, it was because of that

Answer (score 1):

Try working in for loop with a product object directly.

`var amount:number;
   for (var product in MyProducts) {
   amount += (product['amount'])*product['quantity'];
}`